# Error: Do you have azure>=2.0.0 installed?

Tags: python, azure, ansible

I am getting below error when I run ansible playbook:

> Do you have azure>=2.0.0 installed? Try `pip install 'azure>=2.0.0' --upgrade`- No module named containerservice

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.4.0.0
config file = /var/www/Ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/home/vagrant/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.12 (default, Jul 18 2016, 15:02:52) [GCC 4.8.4]
```

Azure:

```
Name: azure
Version: 2.0.0rc5
Summary: Microsoft Azure Client Libraries for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python
Author: Microsoft Corporation
Author-email: ptvshelp@microsoft.com
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: azure-servicemanagement-legacy, azure-batch, azure-servicebus, azure-mgmt, azure-storage, azure-graphrbac
```

I tried to install this: `pip install azure-mgmt-containerservice` But, now below error is coming:

> Installed resource client version is 0.30.0rc5. The supported version is 1.1.0. Try `pip install azure>=2.0.0 --upgrade`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to fix this is to reinstall ansible with

```
pip install ansible[azure]
```

this will install all the azure dependencies automatically. there is currently a discrepancy between package(s) in azure 2.0.0 and ansible requirements for 2.4.0.0

ps. your azure module is really outdated. like 2 years outdated.

Comment: I ran the given command. Error: `Do you have azure>=2.0.0 installed? Try `pip install 'azure>=2.0.0' --upgrade`- No module named azure.mgmt.network.models`

Comment: Azure module is outdated means you're talking about `rc5`?

Comment: just delete it (azure module), you probably cannot update from rc5.

Comment: It's working. Thanks! Just installed `msrestazure` package after ansible installation. `sudo -H pip install msrestazure`